# How to add debounce function in ace editor "afterExec" callback?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor, debouncing

Can I make use of debounce while triggering ace editor "afterExec" event?

Comment: Can you provide any code that helps creates a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: editor.commands.on("afterExec", _.debounce( (e)=> {
            if ((e.command.name == "insertstring" && /^[\w.]$/.test(e.args))||  e.command.name=="backspace") {
              editor.execCommand("startAutocomplete")
            }
          }), 4000);

Here debounce is not working

Comment: please add the example to the question, and explain what do you mean by "not working", do you get a specific error, or is the behavior different from what you expect